# Matching the TLD and file extension from the URL

Tags: regex, perl

I am working on a program and need to extract TLD and web page extension from the URL

E.g: `http://www.example.com/somedir/someotherdir/index.html` should give me TLD `.com` and Extension `Html`

While this: `http://www.example.com.au/somedir/someotherdir/index/` should give me TLD `.com.au` and Extension `null`

Is there any way I can do this with Regex in Perl? I am using the URI module in Perl but It cannot seem to do this Type of extraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the URI module, you can easily extract the `host` and `path`. Then it's a simple matter of taking everything after the last dot, or conversely removing everything up to and including the last dot. You may want to get more complicated for the extension, to properly handle cases where there is no extension.

```
($tld = $uri->host) =~ s/.*\.//;

($extension = $uri->path) =~ s/.*\///;
$extension = '' unless $extension =~ s/.*\.//;
```

Comment: Use another delimiter for `s///` to make it more readable. `s{.*/}{}` for example.

Comment: +1 This is the better solution, I am deleting my own post. Slight optimization: `$extension = ($uri->path_segments)[-1]` will extract the last element of the path.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but how do I handle cases such as "http://www.example.com.au/ where the root TLD will include com and au. Getting getting the last part is my main challenge

Comment: @AkinleyeAdedamola: There is no straightforward way to determine whether a particular sequence of labels constitutes a "multi-label TLD" or not. Consider for example .co.uk versus .co.tv. The former is equivalent to .com, or .com.au, while the latter is owned by some company that sells a domain redirection service. About all you could do there is build up a database of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

The regex provided in [RFC-3986 Appendix B](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B) can be modified to accomplish this task:

```pl
if ($urltext =~ m!
    ^                 # Anchor to start of string.
    (?:[^:/?#\s]+:)?  # Optional URI scheme.
    //[^:/?#\s]+\.    # Required (non-IP) host (up to TLD)
    ([^:/?#\s.\d]+)   # $1: Top level domain(TLD)
    (?::\d+)?         # Optional port.
    /                 # Required path separator.
    [^?#\s]*\.        # Path up to file extension.
    ([^?#\s.]+)       # $2: File extension.
    (?:\?[^#\s]*)?    # Optional query.
    (?:\#\S*)?        # Optional fragment.
    $                 # Anchor to end of string.
    !x) {
    $tld = $1;
    $ext = $2;
} else {
    # no match
}
```

(Note: it appears the SO syntax highlighter can't handle Perl 'x' mode regexes)